# How do I implement multiple argument generation using FsCheck?

Tags: f#, fscheck, fsunit

**How do I implement multiple argument generation using FsCheck?**

I implemented the following to support multiple argument generation:

```
// Setup
let pieces =    Arb.generate<Piece> |> Gen.filter (isKing >> not)
                                    |> Arb.fromGen  

let positionsList = Arb.generate<Space list> |> Arb.fromGen
```

I then used these arguments to test the behavior of a function that's responsible for generating move options for a given checker:

```
// Test
Prop.forAll pieces <| fun piece ->
    Prop.forAll positionsList <| fun positionsItem ->

        positionsItem |> optionsFor piece 
                      |> List.length <= 2
```

Is nesting Prop.forAll expressions the right technique when managing multiple generated argument types?

Is there an alternative method for generating multiple arguments for a function under test?

**Here's the entire function:**

```
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``options for soldier can never exceed 2`` () =

    // Setup
    let pieces =    Arb.generate<Piece> |> Gen.filter (isKing >> not)
                                        |> Arb.fromGen  

    let positionsList = Arb.generate<Space list> |> Arb.fromGen

    // Test
    Prop.forAll pieces <| fun piece ->
        Prop.forAll positionsList <| fun positionsItem ->

            positionsItem |> optionsFor piece 
                          |> List.length <= 2
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the solution to my question derived from Mark's answer:

```
[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true, MaxTest=100)>]
let ``options for soldier can never exceed 2`` () =

    // Setup
    let pieceGen =     Arb.generate<Piece> |> Gen.filter (isKing >> not)
    let positionsGen = Arb.generate<Space list>

    // Test
    (pieceGen , positionsGen) ||> Gen.map2 (fun x y -> x,y)
                               |> Arb.fromGen
                               |> Prop.forAll <| fun (piece , positions) -> 
                                                   positions |> optionsFor piece 
                                                             |> List.length <= 2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a general observation, `Arbitrary` values are difficult to compose, whereas `Gen` values are easy. For that reason, I tend to define my FsCheck building blocks in terms of `Gen<'a>` instead of `Arbitrary<'a>`.

With `Gen` values, you can compose multiple arguments using `Gen.map2`, `Gen.map3`, etcetera, or you can use the `gen` computation expression.

**Gen building blocks**

In the OP example, instead of defining `pieces` and `positionsList` as `Arbitrary`, define them as `Gen` values:

```
let genPieces = Arb.generate<Piece> |> Gen.filter (isKing >> not)

let genPositionsList = Arb.generate<Space list>
```

These are 'building blocks' of the types `Gen<Piece>` and `Gen<Space list>`, respectively.

Notice that I named them `genPieces` instead of simply `pieces`, and so on. This prevents name collisions later on (see below). (Also, I'm not sure about the use of the plural *s* in `pieces`, because `genPieces` only generates a single `Piece` value, but I since I don't know your entire domain, I decided to leave that as is.)

If you need only one of them, you can convert it into an `Arbitrary` using `Arb.fromGen`.

If you need to compose them, you can use either one of the map functions, or computation expressions, as shown below. This will give you a `Gen` of tuples, and you can then use `Arb.fromGen` to convert that into an `Arbitrary`.

**Compose using map2**

If you need to compose `pieces` and `positionsList` into an argument list, you can use `Gen.map2`:

```
Gen.map2 (fun x y -> x, y) genPieces genPositionList
|> Arb.fromGen
|> Prop.forAll <| fun (pieces, positionList) -> 
    // test goes here...
```

`Gen.map2 (fun x y -> x, y)` returns a two-element tuple (a *pair*) of values, which you can destructure into `(pieces, positionList)` in the anonymous function.

This example should also make it clear why `genPieces` and `genPositionList` are better names for the `Gen` values: they leave room to use the 'naked' names `pieces` and `positionList` for the generated values passed to the test body.

**Compose using computation expression**

Another alternative that I sometimes prefer for more complex combinations is to use the `gen` computation expression.

The above example could also be written like this:

```
gen {
    let! pieces = genPieces
    let! positionList = genPositionList
    return pieces, positionList }
|> Arb.fromGen
|> Prop.forAll <| fun (pieces, positionList) -> 
    // test goes here...
```

The initial `gen` expression also returns a pair, so it's equivalent to composition with `Gen.map2`.

You can use the option you find most readable.

You can see more examples of non-trivial `Gen` combinations in my article [Roman numerals via property-based TDD](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/06/28/roman-numerals-via-property-based-tdd).

Comment: Thanks Mark. Besides blogs, are there any books on this? I searched the web and am unable to locate a reference book. Hence, I would like to understand the internals of Property-based Testing frameworks at a high-level without being a FP guru.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I'm not aware of any books.

Comment: [CEFP 2009 has a (paid) chapter on QuickCheck about 40 pages long, written by John Hughes.](https://twitter.com/nikosbaxevanis/status/680704605819420672)